# etc/hosts question

Tags: hosts

Sometimes when I'm reading news I click on a headline and it takes me to telegraph.co.uk news which I don't like to read, so I tried to make my hosts file redirect to localhost.  So in my hosts file I put 
127.0.0.1 telegraph.co.uk

which works if I just type in that exact address, but if it has a longer URL it gets through how can I block all telegraph.co.uk articles, including those in this format

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/iraq/6913907/Iraq-hostages-Peter-Moores-kidnapping-masterminded-by-Iran.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

www.telegraph.co.uk and telegraph.co.uk are two **totally different addresses**. Place `127.0.0.1 www.telegraph.co.uk` in your hosts file as well.

This is because the `www.` is simply a subdomain of `telegraph.co.uk`, not a particularly special part of the web. They simply both lead to the same place - but the hosts file is not very clever, you have to be very clear and verbose when blocking things.